# Error "Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist" while trying to access sharepoint landing page

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, asp.net, timer-jobs, content-database

I could access sharepoint central admin, but not sharepoint sites or pages.
Is it something related to connection time outs or content database timer locks?
How to fix this?

### Server Error in '/' Application.

> Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))  Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [COMException (0x80030102): Attempted to use an object that has ceased
>   to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.WebTemplateName(String
>   bstrUrl) +0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.WebTemplateName(String bstrUrl)
>   +127
>
> [SPException: Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   +28020722    Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.WebTemplateName(String bstrUrl)
>   +208    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_WebTemplate() +82    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_WebTemplateConfiguration() +25
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.InitJs_Register(Page page)
>   +606    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.RegisterForControl(Control
>   ctrl, Page page, String name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer,
>   Boolean loadAfterUI, String language) +468
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.Register(Page page, String
>   name, Boolean localizable, Boolean defer, Boolean loadAfterUI, String
>   language, String uiVersion) +155
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.ScriptLink.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +272
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2428

Comment: IS there any visual webpart is there in the landing page

Comment: yes, there are few visual web parts

Answer (score 1):

The error message “`Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED)`)” occurs  you're accessing an object that has been already disposed  in SharePoint. When once disposed it is never accessible anymore.
I suggest that you should debug your code, and check if there is any error or mistake in the code of the new part. Review the entire code once.

please check the [msdn post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/798a26cd-12d9-4ce0-bd67-c54a8955e07d/attempted-to-use-an-object-that-has-ceased-to-exist-exception-from-hresult-0x80030102?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Comment: I didn't think so, I didn't make code any changes, But my application is up and I can browse all the site pages now.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because of the handling of the site object and killing the same to avoid memory leaks, which we handle in code. If on a later moment someone want to add for example a Webpart  SharePoint wants to use this in memory object which unfortunately has ceased to exist because I Killed it.

> > using (SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site)  {
> >     --- }

If it is coded this way to avoid memory leaks which are easily created working with some Sharepoint objects. In my code, If refference my personal object 'site' to the current site object provided by the Sharepoint. But this current site object lives in memory as a SPSite object that Sharepoint wants to keep using. The syntax in my code means that I  kill my object right after the curly break. But because it is not a new object but a 'relation' to Sharepoint's SPContext.Current.Site which is in memory I actualy kill Sharepoints SPContext.Current.Site. If on a later moment I want add for example a webpart  Sharepoint wants to use this in memory object which unfortunatly has seased to exsist because I Killed it.  The exception message in one of the above posts reports that some needed objects are not there anymore.

For example did you use a third party or custom made view/webpart/user control that by accident kills objects in Sharepoint? Is there maybe a bug in some Sharepoint control? Is there another killer?

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add what happened in my case in case it helps someone.

I had this while processing items in a list that had corrupt items.  In the SharePoint UI itself, if you try to view the properties, you get a blank page.  Other lists based on the same custom content were just fine.  So if you can't find any other reason for this error (i.e. actual disposal of objects), check the actual items you're working with for corruption.